# Glide retention in tune, duke, news in the United States

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

In words like *tune*, *duke*, *news* or *student*, most Britons and a sizable minority of Canadians have a sort of *y* glide after the initial consonant or consonant cluster. For these speakers, the words *do* and *due* are pronounced differently.

In the United States, only a small minority of speakers now retain this glide in their everyday speech, though the proportion was much higher in the mid-twentieth century.

[A 1986 study](https://www.jstor.org/stable/455159) by Ann Pitts showed that in northern areas of the United States, where deletion of the glide strongly predominated, it was retained at much higher rates in the news media. For example, the word *Tuesday* had the glide in it in 93 of 156 instances she recorded.

Pitts hypothesized that forms with the glide carried greater prestige in the eyes of Northerners due to their association with British speech, despite the fact that, among Americans, they were present most frequently in the speech of Southerners.

I would like to know to what extent this kind of glide retention (after /s, z, t, d, n, st/) can still be heard in U.S. media today.

Are there particular media figures you can point to who have this trait in their speech?

How do Americans without the glide react on hearing it in the speech of other Americans? Does it sound snobbish? Uneducated? Or does it mostly go unnoticed? (Please note that if at all possible, I would prefer objective information on perceptions of this trait.)

Comment: How do Americans without the glide react to hearing it in the speech of other Americans ... generally they don't notice it at all. For many Americans, the sequences /dju/ and /du/ are now allophones, and they will hear /du/ even if you say /dju/ in the words *do* or *doom*.

Comment: @PeterShor I do hear /dju/ with non-negligible frequency in words like *do* or *doom*, but it still seems like something only a minority of people do. Otherwise, I feel like I'd be hearing it five or ten times more often than I do. I suppose it's possible that I'm hearing it and interpreting it as a highly fronted /du/, but I'm really talking about vowels that would clearly be out of place in the sequences /mu/ or /bu/ in the North.

Comment: I would have thought that how speakers with one dialect react to those with another dialect is more of a sociology question, rather than one that can be answered with objective fact, but in general my guess is that those from parochial communities will react the worst, while those from cosmopolitan areas will be more tolerant.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is sociolinguistics unscientific?